# Error: specified host network collides with a non-hostonly network

Tags: networking, mac, virtualization, vagrant, virtuabox

Below is the error:

```
The specified host network collides with a non-hostonly network!
This will cause your specified IP to be inaccessible. Please change
the IP or name of your host only network so that it no longer matches that of
a bridged or non-hostonly network.

Bridged Network Address: '192.168.1.0'
Host-only Network 'en0: Wi-Fi (Wireless)': '192.168.1.0'
```

---

after running `vagrant up` command from [folder](https://github.com/shamhub/Hands-On-Infrastructure-Monitoring-with-Prometheus/tree/master/chapter03) with below config in `../utils/vagrant_defaults.rb`:

```
GUI     = false
RAM     = 512
DOMAIN  = ".prom.inet"
NETWORK = "192.168.1."
NETMASK = "255.255.255.0"
BOX     = 'bento/ubuntu-18.04'
```

---

On my laptop `ip addr` gives below ip:

```
$ ip addr
    en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500  
         inet 192.168.1.64/24 brd 192.168.1.255 en0
```

---

`vagrant up` launches 3 VM's using Oracle virtual box in the virtual network within laptop in subnet `192.168.1.0`(because my laptop is in that subnet)

1. What is host network?
2. What is non-host network?
3. How to resolve this error? Why cannot host IP network match with non-host network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Host Only network IP range.  Host only is for host use only and not the outside world.

Bridged networking is for unfettered Internet access by the guest.

[Change VBOX host only IP](https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Network_Configuration_in_VirtualBox)

> Host-only Networking
>
> In this mode, communication between connected guest systems and the
> host system is possible.[7]
>
> Customized network interfaces will be used on the host system for the
> host-only network, such as: vboxnet0. The IP address on the host as
> well as the DHCP server for this network will be configured directly
> in VirtualBox:
>
> 1. Select Global Settings from the File menu
> 2. Select the Network item in the list on the left and then right-click on the tool icon.
> 3. The IP address for the host can now be changed in this host-only network
> 4. After clicking on the DHCP Server tab, the DHCP server settings can be changed

Comment: so the packet traffic for thos 3 VM's has separate network stack(`vboxnet0`) which does not collide with host machine network stack(`en0`). Is that correct?

Comment: Change the IP range as I described and then guest packets will not collide with your host machine,

Comment: So, host only network is `vboxnet0` and non-host network is `en0`, in my case, Is that correct?

Comment: Yes and you can set the DHCP range in step 4 above to allow more guests on the one Host Only subnet.

Comment: When you say bridge networking, Is `en0` a TCP/IP layer2 bridge?

Comment: That is your bridge setup (which uses the subnet the host uses from the router).

Comment: How to connect to vm 1(`192.168.42.10`) in host network(`vboxnet0`)? using ssh

Comment: You need to use the iP address (not the machine name) and you may need a NAT connection. Host Only is designed to prevent connections.